# Incorrect Location Attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, identify

I'm currently running ArcGIS 10.4.1 and am experiencing incorrect location attributes of point features when I inspect them using the Identify tool. The Location attribute changes every time the respective point is 're-identified'. I first noticed this in an existing project with a point Shapefile I was generating using ArcPy, but the problem persists in different coordinate systems and after starting a new, blank MXD.

For example, if I download this free point Shapefile from the URL below, load it into a blank map and inspect any point using the Identify tool, then close the Identify window re-identify it, the Location value will have changed considerably (sometimes up to 1 km). This happens every time I repeat the Identify process. The location given in the lower-right corner of the map window however is *correct*.

[Free Shapefile Download - USA Pollutant Map](http://www.mapcruzin.com/epa-criteria-pollutant-shapefiles/co.zip)

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: The fact that the "correct" and "incorrect" values are at least close (up to the thousands place), tells me that it is probably a projection issue of some kind.  When you "hover" your mouse pointer over one of the points in your data frame, does the bottom right readout in ArcMap match the Northing/Easting or the Locations value you demonstrated?

Comment: Thanks GeoJohn, the location in the lower right hand corner is consistent with the field values of Easting and Northing, which further indicates the problem is with the 'Location' attribute.

EDIT: I've just noticed that if I close the Identify window and reopen it, the 'Location' is different each time (often varying by several metres in X and Y). This occurs without changing any parameters on the map, simply closing and re-opening the Identify window. Really odd...

Comment: Yah, that is really strange behavior...  Maybe try exporting the generated points as a new FC and start with a fresh MXD, just to make sure there isn't some kind of bug happening here.

Comment: Again, thanks GeoJohn. I've just started with a fresh MXD and created a fresh point shapefile using my script (not even a background map has been added). Same result; the Location XY attributes change (often by several hundred metres) each time I close and reopen the Identify window.

Comment: On further investigation, this issue is occurring even after starting with a fresh map, a point shapefile from external sources, and a different coordinate system. I've updated the original question to reflect this.

Comment: Nothing strange, it depends on coordinates of a click with Identify tool. It is not coordinate of actual feature. Activate I tool, click outside point and drag around the point to see what I mean. Alternatively click in empty space

Comment: @FelixIP I think your comment would be suitable as an answer

Comment: This is how the identify tool works.  It identifies the cursor location, not the feature

Answer (score 1):

Nothing strange, it depends on coordinates of a mouse pointer click with Identify tool. 
It is not coordinate of actual feature. Activate I tool, click outside point and drag around the point to see what I mean.

Alternatively click in empty space, this will also have some "location" pair